# Use a JS string variable passed in as a parameter as the value of a data parameter in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the relative Javascript that is not working quite right. The parameter **thisChartData** is a string and it alerts just fine; it's generated by a PHP script elsewhere (but that's not important).

If I copy and paste what the alert output into the data section the chart generates fine. But for some reason I can't use the parameter name in the data section

```
            function drawChart( thisChartData, thisChartTitle ) {
                var ctx = $("#my-chart");
                alert(thisChartData); // alerts->    '131', '1043', '144', '43'

            //chart data
                var ctxData = {                     
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [ thisChartData ], //using the paramter variable doesn't work
                        backgroundColor: [ <?php echo $bg_color_list; ?> ]                      
                    }]
                };
```

Meanwhile the code below works fine, I need the data to be variable depending on what I pass to the function because I'm going to have several data sets I want to scroll through.

```
     function drawChart( thisChartData, thisChartTitle ) {
            var ctx = $("#my-chart");
            alert(thisChartData); // alerts->    '131', '1043', '144', '43'

        //chart data
            var ctxData = {                     
                datasets: [{
                    data: [ '131', '1043', '144', '43' ], 
                    backgroundColor: [ <?php echo $bg_color_list; ?> ]                        
                }]
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data: [ thisChartData ]` should just be `data: thisChartData`, and when you call `drawChart`, pass in an array. E.g.:

```
function drawChart( thisChartData, thisChartTitle ) {
    var ctx = $("#my-chart");

    //chart data
    var ctxData = {                     
        datasets: [{
            data: thisChartData,  // <======
            backgroundColor: [ <?php echo $bg_color_list; ?> ]                      
        }]
    };
```

and

```
drawChart(['131', '1043', '144', '43'], "title");
```

Comment: Yes that's how I needed to do it. Thank you for your help!